# Projections on the Riemann Sphere are antipodal

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Prove that given two points $z,w\in\mathbb{C}$, we have that their projections on the Riemann sphere are antipodal if and only if: $z\bar{w}=-1$.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [If $z\bar{z}'=-1$, do $z$ and $z'$ correspond to opposite points on the Riemann sphere?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/102855/if-z-barz-1-do-z-and-z-correspond-to-opposite-points-on-the-riemann)

Comment: Yes this is a dupe of what you linked, @666User666.  So why, instead of closing this as a dupe, did you vote today to bounty this, to protect it from closure, while simultaneously announcing in CURED the need to delete three other posts (despite your recognizing six days ago that this post is in fact, of the very post you link above?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We could of course just compute it using the explicit formula for the stereographic projection. But let's argue geometrically.

Let $z \in \mathbb{C}\setminus\{0\}$ and $\zeta$ the image of $z$ on the sphere under stereographic projection. Let $C$ be the great circle on the sphere passing through $\zeta$ and the north and south pole.

Let $\varphi$ be the angle between the plane and the line connecting $z$ with the north pole $N$. Since the radius of the sphere is $1$, the distance of $z$ from the intersection of the plane and the axis of the sphere (that is, $0 \in \mathbb{C}$) is $\cot \varphi$, i.e. $\lvert z\rvert = \cot \varphi$.

The line connecting $\zeta$ and its antipodal point $\alpha := -\zeta$ is a diameter of $C$, hence, by Thales' theorem, the triangle $\alpha N\zeta$ has a right angle at $N$. $\angle z 0N$ is a right angle, hence $\angle 0N\zeta = \angle 0Nz = \frac{\pi}{2}-\varphi$, and therefore $\angle 0N\alpha = \varphi$. But that means the line $N\alpha$ intersects the plane at a distance of $\tan\varphi$ from $0$, on the opposite side of $z$, and that means the point projected to $\alpha$ is $$w = -\frac{z}{\lvert z\rvert^2},$$

whence $z\overline{w} = -1$.

Conversely, if $z\overline{w} = -1$, and $w$ is projected to $\beta$ on the sphere, then $\lvert w\rvert = \tan \varphi$, whence $\angle \beta N0 = \varphi$, and since $w$ (and $\beta$) lie on the opposite side of $0$ from $z$, we have

$$\angle \beta N\zeta = \angle \beta N0 + \angle 0N\zeta = \varphi + \left(\frac{\pi}{2} - \varphi\right) = \frac{\pi}{2},$$

and by Thales, the line segment connecting $\beta$ and $\zeta$ is a diameter of the great circle $C$, hence $\beta = -\zeta$ is the antipodal point of $\zeta$.

---

Analytically, with the explicit formulae of the stereographic projection

$$\begin{align}
\varphi \colon z = x+iy &\mapsto \left(\frac{2x}{x^2+y^2+1},\,\frac{2y}{x^2+y^2+1},\,\frac{x^2+y^2-1}{x^2+y^2+1} \right)\\
\varphi^{-1} \colon (\alpha,\,\beta,\,\gamma) &\mapsto \frac{1}{1-\gamma}(\alpha + i \beta)
\end{align}$$

we obtain that the point being projected to the antipodal point of $z$'s projection is

$$\begin{align}
w &= \varphi^{-1} \left(\frac{-2x}{x^2+y^2+1},\,\frac{-2y}{x^2+y^2+1},\, \frac{1-x^2-y^2}{x^2+y^2+1}\right)\\
&= \frac{x^2+y^2+1}{2(x^2+y^2)}\frac{-2(x+iy)}{x^2+y^2+1}\\
&= \frac{-(x+iy)}{x^2+y^2}\\
&= -1/\overline{z}.
\end{align}$$

Comment: Thanks, this is a good a geometric argument, but analytically, how can I do?

Comment: I've added the (somewhat boring) calculation with the explicit formulae.

Comment: Ohh, thanks very much. I'm very grateful

Comment: @DanielFischer How did you pass at the calculations from line 1 to line 2( from paranthesis I mean to out of them) ?

Comment: @user123 I believe the first and second lines in the final computation? We have the general formula $\varphi^{-1}(\alpha,\beta,\gamma) = \frac{1}{1-\gamma}(\alpha + i\beta)$, which is noted above. In the computation, we have $\alpha = \frac{-2x}{x^2 + y^2 + 1}$, $\beta = \frac{-2y}{x^2+y^2+1}$ and $\gamma = \frac{1-x^2-y^2}{x^2+y^2+1}$. So $\alpha + i \beta = \frac{-2(x+iy)}{x^2+y^2+1}$, and $1-\gamma = \frac{(x^2+y^2+1) - (1-x^2-y^2)}{x^2+y^2+1} = \frac{2(x^2+y^2)}{x^2+y^2+1}$. Then multiply $\frac{1}{1-\gamma}$ with $(\alpha + i\beta)$ and simplify (cancel common factors).

Comment: Oh I got it thanks alot :) @DanielFischer

Comment: Why do we know $\angle \zeta 0N$ is a right angle? I think it would be a right angle if $\zeta$ and $\alpha$ were antipodal points on the unit circle of $\mathbb C$ but I don't see how $\angle \zeta 0N$ can be a right angle if $\zeta$ and $\alpha$ are not on the unit circle.

Comment: @user398843 That's a typo, it ought to be $\angle z0N$. Thanks for spotting it.

Comment: Could you please add some pictures, I'm having difficulty understanding your answer

Comment: Shouldn't $ON \zeta $ be the one with $\phi$??? @DanielFischer rather than one with anti podal

Answer (score 4):

For points $z$, $w\in{\mathbb C}$ with antipodal stereographic projections to $S^2$ the triangle with vertices $z$, $N$, $w$ has a right angle at $N$. By a Pythagorean theorem ("Höhensatz") it follows that $$|z|\>|w|=1^2\ .\tag{1}$$ Furthermore, looking at the situation from high up on the $x_3$-axis we see that $$\arg(w)=\arg(z)+\pi\ \tag{2}$$
The equations $(1)$ and (2) together easily imply $z\>\bar w=-1$.