# Subgroup of Möbius transformations which are isometries with respect to the standard metric on the Riemann sphere

Tags: complex-analysis, metric-spaces, isometry, mobius-transformation, stereographic-projections

I'm trying to find which subgroup of Mobius transformations are isometries with respect to the standard metric on the Riemann sphere (the one induced from the Euclidean metric on $\mathbb{R}^3$).

The question hints that the distance on the Riemann sphere corresponds to the distance function on $\mathbb{P}^1$ given by

$$d(L_1,L_2) = 2\sqrt{1 - \frac{|\langle v,w \rangle|^2}{||v||^2||w||^2}}$$

where $ v \in L_1\backslash\{0\}$ and $w \in L_2\backslash\{0\}$, and that a Mobius map corresponds to the action of a matrix $A \in GL_2(\mathbb{C})$ on lines in $\mathbb{C}^2$, and asks me to consider which $2x2$ matrices automatically preserve this expression for $d$.

I honestly have no idea where to start with this question, so I'd really appreciate whatever help you might be able to give.

Comment: From the expression of $d$, it is clear that a Mobius transformation $A$ preserves the metric $d$ if $A$ preserves the inner product $\left<\cdot,\cdot\right>$, ie, $A$ is a rotation matrix. If you adopt the well-known fact that the isometry group of a sphere is the rotation group, then it follows that the subgroup is just the rotation group.

Comment: @cjackal note that one has to mod out $\mathbb C^*$ in the $GL(2, \mathbb C)$ action, so the subgroup in $GL(2, \mathbb C)$ is definitely not the rotation group. On the other hand, there is no point to do this exercise, if one assume the knowledge about the isometry group of the sphere.

Comment: @ArcticChar Well we need to consider the matrices projectively, so $A$ is considered as an element in $PSL(2,\mathbb{C})$ and my comment is just rephrasing the isomorphism $PSU(2,\mathbb{C})\cong SO(3)$. But it is true that my first comment is confusing in not distinguishing the complex inner product and real inner product. One may want to use an explicit formula converting a complex 2x2 matrix to a real 4x4 matrix to see the isomorphism above.

Answer (score 1):

Note this could be all wrong.

It seems to me the isometries of the unit sphere in $\Bbb R^3$ are rotations. Hence it seems very clear that $R_t$ leaves that metric invariant, if $$R_t(z)=e^{it}z$$for some $t\in\Bbb R$.

I bet $\phi\circ R_t\circ\phi^{-1}$ is also an isometry; not willing to conjecture whether those are the only ones. (Of course there's also the question of giving a more intrinsic description. I bet that it's not hard to see that the $\phi\circ R_t\circ\phi^{-1}$ are precisely the Mobius transformatiions that fix exactly two points... (that would follow if the only transformations fixing $0$ and $\infty$ were the $R_t$.))

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to answer this question despite it being 3 years old because I wondered the same thing and saw that the answers here were not clear. So it is in an easy to find spot, here is my answer. The subgroup of $PGL(\mathbb{C},2)$ is $PSU(2)$.

First, let us show that if $A=\begin{bmatrix}a & b \\ c & d\end{bmatrix}$ is an isometry then it is unitary. We start by normalizing and so $\det A=ad-bc=1$. As noted by [David C. Ullrich](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3061218) isometries must be elliptic, i.e. the characteristic constant $\lambda$ has $|\lambda|=1$ or equivalently $\operatorname{Tr} A=a+d\in(-2,2)$. However, it is not clear what $\phi$ is, in David's answer. If it is taken to be any Möbius transformation, then this is not correct because the fixed points of the isometry are where the axis of rotation intersects the sphere and therefore are antipodal.

If $c=0$, then $\infty$ is fixed and therefore $0$ is also fixed and $b=0$. So, $d=a^{-1}$ and $A$ is unitary.

If $c\neq0$, then the fixed points are $$z_0^+=\frac{a-d+\sqrt{(a+d)^2-4}}{2c}$$ and $$z_0^-=\frac{a-d-\sqrt{(a+d)^2-4}}{2c}.$$ We note that because $A$ defines an elliptic transformation, $(a+d)^2-4<0$. So we rewrite the fixed points as $$z_0^+=\frac{a-d+i\sqrt{4-(a+d)^2}}{2c}$$ and $$z_0^-=\frac{a-d-i\sqrt{4-(a+d)^2}}{2c}.$$ From [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/480891/projections-on-the-riemann-sphere-are-antipodal), we have that $$z_0^+\overline{z_0^-}=\frac{|a-d|^2+2i\operatorname{Re}(a-d)\sqrt{4-(a+d)^2}+(a+d)^2-4}{4|c|^2}=-1.$$ Because $-1$ is real and $\sqrt{4-(a+d)^2}$ has to be non-zero we conclude that $\operatorname{Re}(a-d)=0$. So $a+d$ is real and $a-d$ is purely imaginary. Therefore, $d=\bar{a}$ and we get $$|a-\bar{a}|^2+(a+\bar{a})^2-4=4|\operatorname{Im}(a)|^2+4(\operatorname{Re}(a))^2-4=4|a|^2-4=-4|c|^2$$ or simply $|a|^2+|c|^2=1$. Using that $\det A=1$, we get $b=-\bar{c}$. Therefore, $A\in PSU(2)$.
The other direction follows from unitary matrices preserving the inner product used in defining the metric.